# Reducing redundant index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `q` that is indexed by drug and dosage form. I noticed that the dataframe shows the same index `plavix` in two different positions when the dataframe is not sorted.  I was able to fix this issue by adding `.sort_index()` to the end of `q` (see Output 1). I have two questions: (1) is there a better way to achieve Output 1; and (2) how could I achieve Output 2 below. Thanks.

```
q = pd.DataFrame(np.array([1,2,3,4]), index=[pd.Series(['plavix', 'warfarin', 
                 'plavix', 'plavix'], index=[0,1,2,3]), pd.Series(['tab', 
                 'inj', 'cap', 'tab'], index=[0,1,2,3])], columns=['app_num'])
```

Output:

```
                app_num
plavix   tab        1
warfarin inj        2
plavix   cap        3
         tab        4
```

Output 1:

```
                app_num
warfarin inj        2
plavix   cap        3
         tab        1
         tab        4
```

Output 2:

```
                app_num
warfarin inj        2
plavix   cap        3
         tab        1
                    4
```

Comment: **HACK**  `q.set_index(np.array('').repeat(len(q)), append=True).sort_index()`

Comment: Worked nicely, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For output 1, you'll need a simple `sort_index`.

```
q.sort_index(level=0, ascending=False)

              app_num
warfarin inj        2
plavix   tab        1
         tab        4
         cap        3
```

For output 2, you'll need to append an extra level before sorting the index.

```
q.set_index(
    q.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount(), append=True
).sort_index(level=[0, 1], ascending=[False, True])

                app_num
warfarin inj 0        2
plavix   cap 0        3
         tab 0        1
             1        4
```